# Copying specific data from one db to another in Azure Sql Db

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, data-migration, azure-sql-server, cross-database

How can we select some data from a table in DB1 and insert into table in DB2 in Azure sql Server without using Azure Data Factory ? I have searched the internet and I found about using SSMS to generate query for data and run that query in DB2 but the problem is that data is too huge to do so, also tried doing a python script by making connections between databases but python is not able to allocate such huge memory.
Note : It's different than usual SQL servers where simple select and insert works by using db names at the start, azure doesn't allow you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using SSIS, I created OLEDB Source and OLEDB Destination and did the migration, it was fast and easy. So to answer my own question, SSIS is useful in this case.